# Is there API that can make possible for a browser to PUSH media chunk to another browser

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner and I am trying to set up a peer-assisted media streaming system, that will work over the web browser. I wish to a server to 'push' media segments to a few clients and then any of these client browsers to push media segment to other client browsers.

I got to know that HTTP/2.0 can make this possible, but I found examples on a server to a client browser.
I came across WebRTC technology. however, could not find anything like PUSH technique among client browser.
I came across WebSocket technology. I found that it does PUSHing from the only server to the client. 
Kindly direct.

Comment: Yes, it's called WebRTC. It's not called push, but does what you required

Comment: Yes. WebRTC is what you're looking for. It requires you to run a ICE (STUN/TURN) server so that peers can introduce themselves to one another, and you'll have limited success setting up direct p2p connections in many scenarios, so you have to pay relaying costs for those peers that can't connect directly to one another. We use [COTURN](https://github.com/coturn/coturn). https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/ is a good place to start. This question is too broad. Voting to close.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. However, please enlighten me- whether the push mechanism of HTTP/2.0 can be done using WebRTC?

Comment: @ShresthaTripathy What you get with WebRTC is very basic. It allows you to create connections between peers. These can ship specific types of media or just raw data. It's down to you to implement any protocol using these basic tools. HTTP and WebRTC don't interoperate. You might be able to build something HTTP-like over WebRTC.

Answer (score 0):

You should use WebRTC + Socket or any other signaling media system to do it.
WebRTC will send the media peer to peer and the signaling server should manage which connections to make and when. I've seen similar product on the web yet.
WebSocket is not fast enought to stream media. WebRTC is far better when talking about media.